# Natural log integral inequality

Tags: real-analysis, upper-lower-bounds

I'm trying to show that for $j\geq 2$,

$$\ln(j)\geq \int_{j - 1/2}^{j+1/2} \ln(x) dx$$

After about 7 pages of attempts, I'm just sick of looking at this. I tried just powering through the integral and using a ton of laws of logs and what not, which all seemed futile. I've also tried exponentiating and dealing with it that way, which did not seem to work. I even tried flipping the inequality and trying to get a contradiction and still have no intuition for what might actually lead to the correct solution.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: The log function is concave;  your inequality is a direct consequence of Jensen's inequality.

Comment: Are the bounds of integration $\frac {j+1}{2}, \frac {j-1}{2},$ or rather $j+\frac 12, j-\frac 12\;?$

Comment: In any case the indefinite integral can easily by found by using integration by parts.

Comment: @amWhy The resulting inequality $$\ln j\ge j\,\ln\frac{j+1/2}{j-1/2}+\ln\sqrt{j^2-1/4}-1$$ looks promising, and there might be interesting answers (unfortunately, Jensen's inequality is less known than it deserves).

Comment: With respect to the (now deleted) answer: Making an answer out of a comment *is* fine: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22842/copying-someone-elses-comment-for-an-answer.

Comment: @Martin R Making a mere hint in an answer out of the same (even more explicit) hint in a comment is fine, too?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note:
This was done independently
of Jack D'Aurizio's
answer.
I'm submitting it
because it
goes into more detail.

I show that

$\ln(j)-\frac{1}{24j^2} -\frac{1}{160j^4}
\lt \int_{j - 1/2}^{j+1/2} \ln(x) dx
\lt \ln(j)-\frac{1}{24j^2} 
$.

More generally,
for $m \ge 1$,

$\begin{array}\\
\int_{j - 1/2}^{j+1/2} \ln(x) dx
&= \ln(j)-\sum_{n=1}^{m-1} \frac{1}{j^{2n}(2n+1)2^{2n+1}} -\frac{c}{j^{2m}(2m+1)2^{m+1}}\\
&=\ln(j) - \frac1{24 j^2} - \frac1{160 j^4}- \frac1{896 j^6}-\frac1{4608 j^8}-...\\
\end{array}
$

with the numerator 
of the last term
from $1$ to $2$.

Here is a simple proof
that doesn't use convexity.
Instead,
it splits the integral
into two halves
and recombines them.

$\begin{array}\\
\int_{j - 1/2}^{j+1/2} \ln(x) dx
&=\int_{j - 1/2}^{j} \ln(x) dx+\int_{j}^{j+1/2} \ln(x) dx\\
&=\int_{ -1/2}^{0} \ln(x+j) dx+\int_{0}^{1/2} \ln(x+j) dx\\
&=\int_{ 0}^{1/2} \ln(-x+j) dx+\int_{0}^{1/2} \ln(x+j) dx\\
&=\int_{ 0}^{1/2} (\ln(-x+j)+\ln(x+j)) dx\\
&=\int_{ 0}^{1/2} \ln(j^2-x^2) dx\\
&=\int_{ 0}^{1/2} (\ln(j^2)+\ln(1-(x/j)^2)) dx\\
&=\ln(j)+\int_{ 0}^{1/2} \ln(1-(x/j)^2) dx\\
&<\ln(j)
\qquad\text{since } \ln(1-(x/j)^2) < 0
\text{ for } 0 < x \le 1/2\\
\end{array}
$

Additionally,
since
$\ln(1-z) < -z$
for $0 < z < 1$,

$\begin{array}\\
\int_{ 0}^{1/2} \ln(1-(x/j)^2) dx
&\lt \int_{ 0}^{1/2} -(x/j)^2 dx\\
&= -\frac{x^3}{3j^2}|_0^{1/2}\\
&= -\frac{1}{24j^2}\\
\end{array}
$

Therefore
$\int_{j - 1/2}^{j+1/2} \ln(x) dx
\lt \ln(j)-\frac{1}{24j^2}
$.

For a lower bound,
for $0 < z < \frac12$,

$\begin{array}\\
-\ln(1-z)
&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{z^n}{n}\\
&=z+\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{z^n}{n}\\
&=z+\frac12\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{z^n}{n/2}\\
&<z+\frac12\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} z^n\\
&<z+\frac{z^2}{2(1-z)}\\
&<z+z^2\\
\end{array}
$

so

$\begin{array}\\
\int_{ 0}^{1/2} \ln(1-(x/j)^2) dx
&\gt \int_{ 0}^{1/2} (-(x/j)^2-(x/j)^4) dx\\
&= -(\frac{x^3}{3j^2}+\frac{x^5}{5j^4})|_0^{1/2}\\
&= -\frac{1}{12j^2} -\frac{1}{160j^4}\\
\end{array}
$

Therefore
$\int_{j - 1/2}^{j+1/2} \ln(x) dx
\gt \ln(j)-\frac{1}{12j^2} -\frac{1}{160j^4}
$.

By taking more terms
in the series for
$\ln(1-z)$,
we can get
a more accurate approximation.

---

And here's how this is done.

$\begin{array}\\
-\ln(1-z)
&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{z^n}{n}\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{m-1} \frac{z^n}{n}+\sum_{n=m}^{\infty} \frac{z^n}{n}\\
&<\sum_{n=1}^{m-1} \frac{z^n}{n}+\sum_{n=m}^{\infty} \frac{z^n}{m}\\
&<\sum_{n=1}^{m-1} \frac{z^n}{n}+\frac{z^m}{m}\sum_{n=m}^{\infty} z^{n-m}\\
&<\sum_{n=1}^{m-1} \frac{z^n}{n}+\frac{z^m}{m(1-z)}\\
\text{and}\\
-\ln(1-z)
&>\sum_{n=1}^{m-1} \frac{z^n}{n}+\frac{z^m}{m}\\
\text{so that}\\
-\ln(1-z)
&=\sum_{n=1}^{m-1} \frac{z^n}{n}+\frac{cz^m}{m}\qquad \text{where }1 < c < 2\\
\end{array}
$

Therefore,
for $m \ge 1$,

$\begin{array}\\
\int_{ 0}^{1/2} \ln(1-(x/j)^2) dx
&= \int_{ 0}^{1/2} (\sum_{n=1}^{m-1} \frac{(x/j)^{2n}}{n}+\frac{c(x/j)^{2m}}{m}) dx\\
&= \sum_{n=1}^{m-1} \int_{ 0}^{1/2} \frac{(x/j)^{2n}}{n}dx+\int_{ 0}^{1/2} \frac{c(x/j)^{2m}}{m} dx\\
&= \sum_{n=1}^{m-1} \frac{x^{2n+1}}{j^{2n}(2n+1)} |_{ 0}^{1/2} +\frac{cx^{2m+1}}{j^{2m}(2m+1)} |_{ 0}^{1/2}\\
&= \sum_{n=1}^{m-1} \frac{1}{j^{2n}(2n+1)2^{2n+1}} +\frac{c}{j^{2m}(2m+1)2^{m+1}}\\
\end{array}
$

Therefore

$\begin{array}\\
\int_{j - 1/2}^{j+1/2} \ln(x) dx
&= \ln(j)-\sum_{n=1}^{m-1} \frac{1}{j^{2n}(2n+1)2^{2n+1}} -\frac{c}{j^{2m}(2m+1)2^{m+1}}\\
&=\ln(j) - \frac1{24 j^2} - \frac1{160 j^4}- \frac1{896 j^6}-\frac1{4608 j^8}-...\\
\end{array}
$

with the numerator 
of the last term
from $1$ to $2$.

Answer (score 5):

$\log(x)$ is a concave function on $\mathbb{R}^+$, hence your inequality is a straightforward consequence of the [Hermite-Hadamard inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite%E2%80%93Hadamard_inequality). It is not difficult to strengthen, too. For any $j\geq 1$ we have

$$ \int_{j-1/2}^{j+1/2}\log(x)\,dx = \int_{0}^{1/2}\log\left(j^2-x^2\right)\,dx = \log(j) +\underbrace{\int_{0}^{1/2}\log\left(1-\frac{x^2}{j^2}\right)\,dx}_{J} $$
where $J\leq 0$ is trivial and Jensen's inequality gives $J\leq \log\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{24j^2}\right).$

Comment: There you are! We were almost worried a bit.

Comment: And by taking more terms in the expansion of $\ln(1-z)$ we can get more exact approximations.